# Bug in Transpose in Mathematica 12.2?

Tags: list-manipulation, compatibility, version-12.2

```
*In[1]=* Transpose[{a, b}]
```

returned in earlier versions of Mathematica (e.g Mathemtica 12.1) simply

```
*Out[1]=* Transpose[{a, b}]
```

together with the warning: "Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {a,b} cannot be transposed."

However in Mathematica 12.2 (on Windows10) the output is:

```
*Out[1]=* {a,b}
```

The Transpose has disappeared. Is this a bug or a feature?

For me, it is problem, because this new behavior is breaking my existing code, where I have functions similar to:

```
getfromdatabase[key_String]:=CallToCppCodeAndReturnListsOfValues[key]
getfromdatabase[expr_]:=expr/. key_String :>  getfromdatabase[key]
```

In previous versions (<12.2) users of my code could execute

```
getfromdatabase[ Transpose[{"firstname", "lastname", "salary"-"rent"}] ]
```

and the output was for example:

```
{ {David, Smith, somenumber}, {Lisa, Garbo, someothernumber}, ... }
```

Now, in 12.2, one gets:

```
{ {David, Lisa,...}, {Smith, Garbo, ...}, {somenumber, someothernumber, ...}}
```

How can I change getfromdatabase to get back the old output using the same input as before?
(Sure, in the example above, one could apply Transpose after calling the function. But in other calls there might be calls of Transpose more nested inside the expression, like `getfromdatabase[ Transpose[{"firstname", "lastname", Transpose[{"salary","rent"}]] ]`)
Thanks!

Comment: As I understand it, the output in 12.2 is in accordance with the documentation "The Wolfram Language represents vectors as lists, and never needs to distinguish between row and column cases. Vectors in the Wolfram Language can always mix numbers and arbitrary symbolic or algebraic elements. The Wolfram Language uses state-of-the-art algorithms to bring platform-optimized performance to operations on extremely long, dense, and sparse vectors. "

Comment: I did not notice this before, but I noticed that `Transpose[{}]` is `{}`, which for me was a very welcome change. Note that `Transpose[{{}}]` is `{}`.

Comment: Regarding the code you say was "broken" by this: I would not have been comfortable doing something like this in previous versions either. Relying on such non-evaluation seems extremely fragile. Also, `Transpose[{1, 2, 3}]` showed an error message in previous versions. Relying on specific details of how an error was handled before just isn't a good idea.

Comment: I can confirm that this was an intended change in WL 12.2. Note that Transpose[{a, b}, {1}] always worked, returning {a, b}. But it was not automatic behavior, and now it is. This has several advantages, for example the fact that now the common expression Transpose[w].m.v works, where w and v are vectors and m is a matrix.

Comment: Are there calls like `expr = Transpose[{"firstname", "lastname"}, Transpose[{"salary", "rent"}]]; getfromdatabase[ expr]` (i.e. `expr` for `getfromdatabase` is first stored in a variable) in your code?

Comment: @ xzczd: Potentially, yes. However, this is a less likely scenario. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, indeed, it turns out that my design was bad. I guess my original idea was that each string in expr is replaced by the corresponding list of values before expr is evaluated. A solution with HoldAll or HoldFirst, similar to the one suggested below by thorimur would be best.

Comment: @jose: The possibilty of Transpose[w].m.v is indeed a nice thing. I just wonder, why Wolfram is not mentioning this change in the documentation. Or did it just overlook it?

Comment: Because the solution in thorimur's answer i.e. making use of `HoldAll` won't work in this case.

Comment: Your are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, in some part of your code, you check for the head `Transpose` being present. So, you can make your own head `t` that behaves like the old transpose, then check for the head `t` instead of `Transpose` in those parts of the code. You could possibly define it like this:

```
t[list : {__List}] := Transpose[list]
t[list_, spec_] := Transpose[list, spec]
```

so that only lists of lists will be *actually* transposed, and the rest will remain enclosed with `t`, as no definition is matched.

Then, we need to give `getfromdatabase` the attribute `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`, rename the previous definition of `getfromdatabase` internally as, say, `getfromdatabase0`, and replace `Transpose` heads with `t` before passing to `getfromdatabase0`. E.g.:

```
SetAttributes[getfromdatabase, HoldAll]
getfromdatabase[expr_] := getfromdatabase0[ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. Transpose -> t]]
```

This is, of course, just one way to fix your code; disclaimer that there might be other, better ways! :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that should work for the specific problem with Transpose. I guess for me the better solution would be to hold the expression unevaluated before the strings are replaced by the lists of values.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by thorimur's answer, I came up with the following, which meets maybe better my original intention of how getfromdatabase should work in general.

```
SetAttributes[getfromdatabase, HoldFirst]
getfromdatabase[key_String]:=CallToCppCodeAndReturnListsOfValues[key]
getfromdatabase[expr_]:=ReleaseHold[ Hold[expr]/. key_String :>  getfromdatabase[key] ]
```

However, with this, I do not exactly get back the behavior of my function in ML <12.2. I need to check if this has unwanted side effects for some users. If yes, thorimur's procedure will be better for me, because it specifically adresses the problem with Transpose.