# Why can't I get the right dimension of matrix?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

This is an example of the output that I get. I am working on with more complicated matrix, but it seemed not working. That's why I try to use a simple number to find the issue. So, my matrix is a 3x1. If I transpose it, it should be a 1x3 matrix. Then I try to multiply both matrices 3x1 * 1x3 respectively. The output should be a 3x3 matrix, right? But unfortunately, the output from Mathematica doesn't give the answer that I want. Here I attached the image of the result;[image]

Comment: Please show us the code text rather than a screenshot of it, so we can easily test. Then, do notice that, for matrix handling, MATLAB and _Mathematica_ are similar but not exactly the same. (You're guessing the syntax of _Mathematica_ based on that of MATLAB, right? )

Comment: Also, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244659/1871

Comment: Try ky = Outer[List, {9, 7, 1}] and kt=Transpose[ky]. Use Dot (.) not *.

Comment: MMA does not have the concept of row and column vectors. Instead "Dot" acts on the last index of the left hand side and the first index of the right hand side. Read about the concept of arrays, vector , matrices in MMA.

Comment: Another related post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/574/1871

Comment: Compare: `Dimensions[{9, 7, 1}]` vs. `Dimensions[{{9, 7, 1}}]` vs. `Dimensions[{{9}, {7}, {1}}]` and then use the `Dot` operator for matrix multiplication where defined.

Comment: In your definition of `kt` you included the display wrapper `MatrixForm`; consequently, `kt` would not be a matrix. Never include display wrappers in the definition, but rather wrap the definition, i.e., `MatrixForm[kt = Transpose[ky]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is best to avoid assigning values wrapped in `MatrixForm` to variables.  Values so wrapped no longer participate in algebraic expressions normally.  `MatrixForm` should generally only be used when displaying a final result.

Second, `*` multiplies vectors element-wise.

Third, *Mathematica* tends to gloss over the distinction between column-vectors and row-vectors.  For example, `Transpose` applied to a list (vector) returns the list unchanged:

```
ky === Transpose[ky]
(* True *)
```

**Option #1 - use `Dot` after converting the column and row vectors to matrices**

The *Mathematica* `Dot` operator produces the matrix product when applied to two matrices but only the scalar product when applied to two vectors.  We can get the desired result by "upgrading" the vectors to be matrices  of dimension one in the row or column direction.

```
krow = {ky}
(* {{9, 7, 1}} *)

kcol = Transpose[krow]
(* {{9}, {7}, {1}} *)

kcol . krow // MatrixForm
```

[image: Dot product]

If the application is going to perform many mixed matrix and vector products, this is probably superior to the second option below.

**Option #2 - use `KroneckerProduct` or `TensorProduct` on the vectors directly**

We can form the matrix direct product of two lists representing vectors using `KroneckerProduct` or `TensorProduct`:

```
ky = {9, 7, 1};
kt = Transpose[ky]
(* {9, 7, 1}, i.e. the same as ky *)

KroneckerProduct[ky, kt] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Kronecker product]

```
TensorProduct[ky, kt] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Kronecker product]

`TensorProduct` can also be used in operator form by typing <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> instead of the original <kbd>*</kbd>.

But beware that these functions will produce higher-order tensor structures than the inputs.  This "upgrading" is precisely what we want in this particular case, but it may not be desirable when chaining together arbitrary matrix and vector products.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a tensor product of a vector by itself, right? If yes, you may act as follows. This is the vector:

```
v = {9, 7, 1};
```

Then this is the tensor:

```
t = Table[v[[i]]*v[[j]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]

(*   {{81, 63, 9}, {63, 49, 7}, {9, 7, 1}}   *)
```

That's how its MatrixForm looks like:

```
t // MatrixForm
```

[image]

There is a more concise way:

```
t=Outer[Times, v, v]
```

returning the same result.

Have fun!