# What does the level mean in the 'transpose'?

Tags: matrix

`Transpose[list,{n1,n2,...}]`

What's the meaning of 'transpose list so that the k-th level in list us the n_k-th level in the result'?

As far as I'm concerned, I thought for a list of 4*4 matrix, the {n1,n2,...} can be {4,2,3,1} or {1,3,2,4} etc., but it was wrong, so what does the {n1,n2,...} mean?

Comment: You should read [tperm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Transpose/tperm.html) which explains it explicitly with an example

Comment: Also, perhaps you could tell what kind of list you are trying to construct

Comment: ……Then why are you using this syntax of `Transpose`? Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/1871

Comment: @xzczd I understand the error, but what's the meaning of Transpose[{1,2,3}, {1}] , that is , why I need the n_k level?

Comment: To understand this last question you should compare `MatrixForm@Transpose[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]` to `MatrixForm@Transpose[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1}]` as a minimal example

Comment: And, in early version `Transpose[{1,2,3}]` isn't even legal: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244659/1871

Comment: Thanks @bmf I have a try, indeed they are different, and using MatrixForm@Transpose[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1, 1}], I get {1,4}, but I still can't understand.

Comment: As mentioned in **Details and Options** section of document of `Transpose`: For a square matrix `m`, `Transpose[m,{1,1}]` returns the main diagonal of `m`, as given by `Diagonal[m]`. »

Comment: If your question is purely on the syntax, I suggest that you work through the examples given in the second link that @xzczd provided. If you are trying to construct a matrix and you don't know how, but you feel `Transpose` is the way, it would be better to tell us the matrix you want to construct.