# ConjugateTranspose[#] vs Conjugate[Transpose[#]] for lists

Tags: functions, matrix, bugs, complex, vector

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier, fixed in 13.0.**

---

I'm getting contradictory behavior for eigenvectors of a matrix when using Conjugate, Transpose and ConjugateTranspose. I'll demonstrate using an example.

```
newmat = {{1, 2, 3 - I}, {4, 5 + 3 I, 6}, {7 - 2 I, 8, 9}}
{nval, nvec} = Eigensystem[newmat] // N // Chop;
```

```
Transpose[nvec[[1]]] == nvec[[1]] (* True *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Conjugate[nvec[[1]]] (* False *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Conjugate[Transpose[nvec[[1]]]] (* False *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] (* False *)
Conjugate[Transpose[nvec[[1]]]] == Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] (* True *)
Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] == Conjugate[nvec[[1]]] (* True *)
```

I'm struggling to understand this behavior. I understand that transpose of the eigenvector is the same as the eigenvector because it is a list with no secondary dimension. However, if so, then shouldn't Conjugate of the vector be the same as it's ConjugateTranspose?

However, if I convert the array/list to a column vector i.e. (n,1) matrix then I get the expected properties.

```
nvec[[1]] = ArrayReshape[nvec[[1]], {Length[nvec[[1]]], 1}];

Transpose[nvec[[1]]] == nvec[[1]] (* False *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Conjugate[nvec[[1]]] (* False *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Conjugate[Transpose[nvec[[1]]]] (* True *)
ConjugateTranspose[nvec[[1]]] == Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] (* True *)
Conjugate[Transpose[nvec[[1]]]] == Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] (* True *)
Transpose[Conjugate[nvec[[1]]]] == Conjugate[nvec[[1]]] (* False *)
```

Kindly help me understand how these functions work in Mathematica. If it's relevant, I come from a physics background (maybe I'm making assumptions that are common for us while not so much for the code). Thanks!

Comment: Please read the manual for `Eigensystem`, in particular the part under "Details and Options".

Comment: Hm. This might also be version dependent. I recall that some time ago it caused an error to call `Transpose` on a vector. With _Mathematica_ 13.2, all the results of your first code block are `True`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes, you're correct - the issue was with my version (12.3.1) which is from July 2021, this is crazy!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher can you please write your comment as an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hm. This might also be version dependent. I recall that some time ago it caused an error to call `Transpose` on a vector. With Mathematica 13.2, all the results of your first code block are `True`.

Comment: "I recall that some time ago it caused an error to call Transpose on a vector. " I guess you mean the issue discussed here?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244659/1871 <strike>I doubt if this is related… </strike> OK, they might have forgotten to tackle `ConjugateTranspose` after changing the behavior of `Transpose`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected, too.